# CSVDE export file-column order wrong?

Tags: csv

I'm using CSVDE to export data from our active directory into a CSV file, which then gets imported into a database.  I'm using the -l switch to specify the columns that I'd like to export, but they don't come out in the same order consistently.  Is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve opening the file in Excel?  This is a nightly batch process and we'd like it to run unattended.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you simply want a command-line utility that can re-order the CSV (and do much else as well), take a look at my FOSS CSV stream editor, [CSVfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix/).

Answer (score 0):

Per the docs:

> LDAP can return attributes in any
>   order, and csvde does not attempt to
>   impose any order on the columns.

How about writing a python script to read reorder the csv file? You may find the [python csv module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) useful for this.