# LDAP Column Order of CSVDE Export

Tags: windows, csv, ldap, csvde

I am facing the problem, that the `csvde.exe` export from an `ActiveDirectory` changes the order of the columns. I am aware of the following line in the `CSVDE` [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc732101%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> LDAP can return attributes in any order, and csvde does not attempt to impose any order on the columns.

I also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698081/csvde-export-file-column-order-wrong). However I was wondering why `LDAP` is returning different orders on different pcs or even on different `queries`. Let me show you an example:

These are the two `commands`:

```
csvde -u -f userdata_it.csv -d "ou=it,dc=your-company,dc=org" -l objectClass,SamAccountName,CN,Distinguishname,memberOf

csvde -u -f userdata_entwicklung.csv -d "ou=entwicklung,dc=your-company,dc=org" -l objectClass,SamAccountName,CN,Distinguishname,memberOf
```

The are exactly the same, expect for the `organisational unit`. But I have a `pc`, that will get the `csv`column order for the first `query`: `objectClass,SamAccountName,CN,Distinguishname,memberOf`

And for the second `query`:
`objectClass,SamAccountName,CN,memberOf,Distinguishname`

I was wondering why this is happening? Because on another `pc`this works like expected. Are there any known solutions? Maybe another program than `csvde`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results of an LDAP search is not repeatable, that is, the ordering is not repeatable, or predictable. LDAP clients must not assume ordering of the entries, attributes, or attribute options in an LDAP search result.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Ordering](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ordering.html)
- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information, it was really helpful to me. However, do you know why `LDAP` doesn't order the results?

Comment: The LDAP standard specifies that LDAP does not order the results (actually is says the ordering is "not repeatable"); speed and simplicity are the driving factors, not ordering of results or relational characteristics.