# CSVDE export issue

Tags: c#, active-directory, csvde

I export all the computer accounts from two different domains with the script below:

```
CSVDE -d "DC=DC,DC...etc." -s servername  -r "(&(objectClass=computer)(!useraccountcontrol:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -f comp.csv -l DN,cn,description,userAccountControl,managedBy
```

The column order for the first domain is: `DN,cn,description,userAccountControl,managedBy`.
If I run the same script for the next one: `DN,cn,userAccountControl,description,managedBy`.

How on earth is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LDAP Column Order of CSVDE Export](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763548/ldap-column-order-of-csvde-export)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speed and simplicity: this is expected behaviour. CSVDE returns results in no particular order. You must not assume the order of results see the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc732101%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) explanation for the -l option.

See [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763548/ldap-column-order-of-csvde-export) on this here at SO.